# POSTGRESQL filter by one field after sort by one field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL.

I have a table with information about **Registry**, that looks like this.

```
                  MyTableName                              
------------------------------------------------------
| id  | registry_id | field_id       | value         |
------------------------------------------------------
| 409 | 71          | 60             | 9925000009417 |
| 410 | 71          | 61             | 5043014134    |
| 411 | 71          | 62             | 55168-LC      |
| 414 | 72          | 60             | 9962202670049 |
| 415 | 72          | 61             | 2272000265    |
| 416 | 72          | 62             | 55122-LC      |
| 419 | 70          | 60             | 9884800823123 |
| 420 | 70          | 61             | 4823006703    |
| 433 | 70          | 62             | 55155-LC      |
| 436 | 76          | 60             | 9934800823123 |
| 437 | 76          | 61             | 4322011999    |
| 438 | 76          | 62             | 3456346267    |
......................................................
......................................................
......................................................
```

I am so sory my English is bad.

1. The aim is to show data after **filtered** and **sort**.
2. We can only one by field for example(`field_id = n`).
3. Also search by any:

- `where field_id = n1 and field_id like '%any_words%'`
- and `where field_id = n2 and field_id like '%any_words2%'`
- and `where field_id = n2 and field_id like '%any_words3%'` ...

If `SORT by field_id` = `N`, search by `filter[field_id1] = '%w1%', filter[field_id2] = '%w2%', filter[field_id3] = '%w3%'.`

For that purpose i'm using this query:

```
SELECT m.registry_id FROM MyTableName as m
ORDER BY case when field_id = N then value end ASC
;
```

Comment: what's your ordering field? and how would you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Does smth. like this fit your needs?

```
WITH C AS
(
SELECT
    id, registry_id, field_id, value,
    row_number() over (order by field_id) as row_num
FROM MyTableName
)
SELECT
    id, registry_id, field_id, value
FROM C where row_num = n1 and value like '%any_words1%'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    id, registry_id, field_id, value
FROM C where row_num = n2 and value like '%any_words2%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided this code:

```
SELECT id, registry_id, registry_attribute_description_id, search_value
FROM  MyTable

WHERE registry_id in (
    SELECT registry_id
    FROM MyTable
    where
        (field_id = 60 and search_value like '%0%')
      OR (field_id = 61 and search_value like '%1%')
      OR (field_id = 62 and search_value like '%2%')
)
and field_id = 58
order by search_value desc
```

All the numbers (integers) are dynamic.